# Logback stops logging on file change

Tags: log4j, logback, rollingfileappender

Wrote a small test and found that when logging to a file and opening that file in vi, editing and then saving it - Logback stops writing to that file.

No apparent errors in the process that is writing the logs. It keeps running but no logs are appended to the file.

Is anyone familiar with this? Tried running the same against log4j - and it appears to continue writing the logs. I recall reading in the past the log4j also had such a shortcoming but couldn't reproduce.

Please advise.

Comment: Is there any chance this is an inode thing?  Like vi is saving a file of the same name, but logback is logging to the inode that the file originally was?  I don't know, but sounds like a bad idea changing a file with an editor while a process is trying to write to the file.